# How to add item to array?

Tags: php, wordpress

The item :

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $loop->post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
```

The array :

```
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
  echo '<img src="'.$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ).'">';
}
```

I need to add the item $img_url in the beginning of the array.

Comment: where is id $img_url? and in which array you want to append it?

Comment: what is `$img_url` I dont even see that.

Answer (score 0):

To add an item to the beginning of an array, you can use [`array_unshift()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

```
<?php
array_unshift($attachment_ids, $img_url);
```